# MYSQL get row count of update from prepared statement in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update, prepared-statement, rowcount

OK I have this code in a stored procedure:

```
       SET @qry = CONCAT('UPDATE ', usermeta_table, ' SET meta_value = ', @token_count, ' WHERE user_id = ', @temp_id, ' AND meta_key = "token_count"');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        SET @did_update = (SELECT ROW_COUNT());

        IF @did_update = 0 THEN

            SET @qry = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', usermeta_table, '(user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (', @temp_id, ', "token_count", ', @token_count, ')');
            PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        END IF;
```

What I'm after is if the update doesn't update any rows then make a row in the table.

For some reason when I run the above code `did_update` is always coming back as 0 so the insert aways happens even if the update has updated some rows. How do I fix this to work?

***UPDATE:*** I've just realised that if the values don't change in the update despite the rows existing it returns zero rows. This is what is causing my logic to break...

Comment: does it matter when you deallocate?

Comment: @tofutim - No it doesn't matter when

Answer (score 4):

According to [this site](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/row_count/),
"you can use ROW_COUNT() with prepared statements, but you need to call it after EXECUTE, not after DEALLOCATE PREPARE, because the row count for allocate prepare is always 0."